# Placing a canvas image (tile) image based on lines of characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a tile system for my game. The way it works is each line is the X and each character in a line is the Y. I decided to create a long string with this data in, here is what I came up with:

```
let tileMap = `
1111111111111111111
1111111NN1111111111
1NNNNNNNNNN11111111
111NNN1111111111111
`;
```

1 being a tile, N is no tile. I do have future plans for 2, 3 and 4 as higher height tiles.

I've tried various algorithms but I can't seem to work out how to do it - the tiles always look like they have been placed with no thought put into it and just messy. I'm not a very good computational thinker so I struggle with this.

Not sure how to embed this, but here is a minimal working example.

https://jsfiddle.net/td5ksbn3/

Answer (score 0):

Your spacing is off. I added two variables:

```
var spacingX = 30;
var spacingY = 30;
```

It is not perfect yet, but you can see your grid.

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let baseImage = new Image();
baseImage.src = 'https://i.imgur.com/CAG8Tgz.png';


let tileMap = `
1111111111111111111
1111111NN1111111111
1NNNNNNNNNN11111111
111NNN1111111111111
`;

var tileRows = tileMap.split('\n');

var spacingX = 0;
var spacingY = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < tileRows.length; x++) {
        spacingX += 40;
    let row = tileRows[x];

    for (let y = 0; y < row.length; y++) {
        spacingY +=23;
        if (row.charAt(y) != 'N') {
            context.drawImage(baseImage, spacingX * 1.5, spacingY * 2);
        }
    }
    spacingY = 30;
}
```

Now it's up to you to tweak the X and Y values. ;)

Look, if you use square tiles (not the ones you used with an angle), this code will make you perfect grids based on your input:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById("gameScreen");

canvas.width = document.body.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.body.clientHeight;

let context = canvas.getContext("2d");

let baseImage = new Image();
baseImage.src = 'https://opengameart.org/sites/default/files/Stone-Tile-3x3-128x128.jpg';


let tileMap = `
1111111111111111111
1111111NN1111111111
1NNNNNNNNNN11111111
111NNN1111111111111
`;

var tileRows = tileMap.split('\n');

var spacingX = 0;
var spacingY = 0;

for (let x = 0; x < tileRows.length; x++) {
        spacingX += 60;
    let row = tileRows[x];

    for (let y = 0; y < row.length; y++) {
        spacingY +=23;
        if (row.charAt(y) != 'N') {
            context.drawImage(baseImage, spacingX * 1.5, spacingY * 2);
        }
    }
    spacingY = 30;
}
```